Why does the untilting functor preserve degrees of finite étale extensions
I have been reading these notes by Bhatt on perfectoid spaces. In theorem 6.2.10 he talks about the untlilting functor from the category of finite etale $K^{\flat}$ extensions to the category of finite etale extensions of $K$ where $K$ is perfectoid. He gives an explicit description of this functor as  $S^\#=W(S°)\otimes_{A_{inf}(K°)}K°[{1\over\pi}] $. The claim is that this functor takes Galois extensions to Galois extensions, and to see this it suffices to see that it preserves degrees along with the fact that it is fully faithful. Here $W(S°)$ is not the usual Witt vectors but the unique deformation of $S°$ along $A_{inf}(K°)\rightarrow(K°^\flat)$.
I am unable to see why this functor preserves degrees.

It is better to correct "elate" in the title.

In another set of notes by Akhil mathew he says that this follows from the fact that if $S/K^{\flat}$ is G-Galois, then G also acts on $S^\sharp$, and that the fixed point set of the G action on $S^\sharp$ is K, since taking fixed points is exact for $\mathbb{Q}$ vector spaces. The action is also faithful since after tilting we get S back again. Then one applies Artin's lemma to conclude the result. But in this argument I am still not able to see that the fixed point set of the G action on $S^\sharp$ is K.
